# Windows neovim vim-plug error: `git` executable not found

Tags: neovim

I have already installed vimplug I can open the file but has no effect on Neovim [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZQR4.png)

Comment: This isn't a well-formed question because it doesn't give the kind of info that other folks who have the same problem will be able to search for. The problem is that your plugin manager expects to use the `git` command to be able to fetch plugins, but you don't have git installed, or at least not available to neovim. If you could include the error message in the title, and copy more into the body, that will help improve the question.

Comment: I actually managed to find this question from a search engine, and the answer from Dylan is the correct one. Please mark as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that your plugin manager (vim-plug) isn't able to run the `git` executable. It needs to do this to fetch the plugins you're trying to load. So install `git`, make sure you can run it from your PowerShell command line, and you should be set.